# Make UIActivityIndicator view run until data is loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, uiactivityindicatorview

I am looking for a simple piece of sample code that shows a UIActivityIndicator view that runs while something is being downloaded from the net. It can be anything, the simpler the better.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  There are lots of examples of how to do this out there.  If you try a couple and have issues with them, then you might try asking specific questions as to the solution you are attempting.  If you have attempted something and it doesn't work, post some of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different problems here:

1. How to use a UIActivityIndicator
2. Download something (asynchronuously) from the net.

These are two *completely separate* problems, and there are plenty of sample code for each of them (for the second one, have a look at [AFNetworking framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) -- everyone uses it).